# how to access a database of one module from another module

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to do some customization in openerp. Now I am just trying to do some data flows from one module to another module, but I am totally confused. please give good instructions to do such a thing.

I have following questions:

1. how to access data's in one module from another one module.
2. how to get data of a particular item (for example in sales getting the data's of sales invoices of a particular customer.
3. Using the loop how to use these all for finding the total amount of all invoices of a customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are general so it's hard to answer precisely to your need, but in general:

1- To get records from any model you have to pool it first like this, then use ORM functions (*browse*, *read*, ...) to get data from it:

```
obj = self.pool.get('my.model.name')
records = obj.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
```

2- To get specific data you can use *search* with a domain to filter data:

```
#return ids where customer field equal to 1
res_ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('customer','=', 1)], context) 

#get records corresponding to res_ids
records = obj.browse(cr, uid, res_ids, context)
```

3- To get the total amount you can do something like this:

```
def get_total_amount(self, cr, uid, customer_id, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('partner_id', '=', customer_id)], context)
    total = 0
    for(rec in obj.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)):
        total = total + rec.amount_total
    return total
```

parameters and return of the function may be changed depending on where you need to use it.